# Counting distinct items in XSLT

Tags: xslt, counting, distinct-values, xslt-grouping

I have XML like this:

```
<assessment>
 <variables>
  <variable>
   <attributes>
    <variable_name value="FRED"/>
   </attributes>
  </variable>
 </variables>
 <variables>
  <variable>
   <attributes>
    <variable_name value="MORTIMER"/>
   </attributes>
  </variable>
 </variables>
 <variables>
  <variable>
   <attributes>
    <variable_name value="FRED"/>
   </attributes>
  </variable>
 </variables>
</assessment>
```

I know that with this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>

 <xsl:template match="assessment">
  <xsl:for-each select=".//variables/variable/attributes/variable_name">
   <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
   <br/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can output the following:

```
FRED 
MORTIMER 
FRED
```

But what I really want to output is this:

```
FRED: 2 
MORTIMER: 1
```

That is, I want to list the distinct elements and how many times each occurs.  Note that I want the elements to appear in the order of their first appearance (which might rule out some solutions that use sorting).

How do I do this?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and efficient solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kValueByVal" match="variable_name/@value"
  use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="
   /*/*/variable/attributes/variable_name/@value
             [generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kValueByVal', .)[1])
             ]
   ">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(., ' ', count(key('kValueByVal', .)), '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document, produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
FRED 2
MORTIMER 1
```

Comment: another good one. Also, I think there should be a tag or something for easily find the answer to all these grouping questions.

Comment: @Alejandro: I created a tag "xslt-grouping". The only thing that remains is for somebody to re-read all 2000+ XSLT questions and re-tag the appropriate ones ... :)

Comment: Thanks!  I posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256791/counting-distinct-items-in-xslt-independent-of-depth